# How to consume a WPF Service in Wordpress

Tags: c#, asp.net, wordpress, web-services, wcf

i am very new to web service and WCF. I want to know that is it possible to consume an WCF Service in WordPress website. 
if yes then where to host the service. 
or what technology (i.e Web Service, asp.net API or WCF service) is better to use for making service, if need to consume the service in WordPress site.

Please give any reference link in this regard.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can pretty much consume any JSON / XML web service using Jquery.   Do a search for Jquery/JavaScript web service call JSON.

Comment: WPF is NOT WCF... Your question is very confusing. Do you want to know  if WCF is an appropriate solution for you or are you asking for alternative solutions to WCF? As for hosting... WCF can be self hosted (in it's own process) or hosted in IIS.

Comment: I want to know that i have created a service in WCF. now i want to use the same service in Wordpress website. is it possible to use the WCF service in wordpress website?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a RESTful WCF service if you so desire, even though I will recommend using ASP.NET WebAPI for this purpose as it suits more.

Please take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35032746/) I've asked, where I've created a simple `HTTP` based WCF service. The purpose of the question is different but you can easily refer the code to create a simple RESTful service in WCF.